# netflix.zuul - org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient:execute - Reason for High Response Times?

Tags: performance, netflix-zuul

Call graph from `/media`.
On tier: Gateway
On node: Gateway

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet:service (method time = 1 ms, total time = 6331 ms)
 HTTPServlet:service:660 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 6330 ms)
  Servlet - dispatcherServlet:doService:943 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 6330 ms)
   Servlet - dispatcherServlet:doDispatch:1040 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 6330 ms)
    Servlet - zuul:service:81 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 6330 ms)
     Servlet - zuul:route:116 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 6329 ms)
      com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner:route:96 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 6329 ms)
       com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor:route:118 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 6329 ms)
        com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor:runFilters:157 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 6329 ms)
         com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor:processZuulFilter:193 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 6329 ms)
          com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter:runFilter:117 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 6329 ms)
           **org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient:execute:118 (method time = 6329 ms, total time = 6329 ms)**

     Servlet - zuul:postRoute:107 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
      com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner:postRoute:87 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
       com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor:postRoute:92 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
        com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor:runFilters:157 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
         com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor:processZuulFilter:193 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
          com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter:runFilter:117 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
           Spring Bean - loggingPostFilter:run:53 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
            com.cubic.cumo.apigateway.filters.logging.RequestLogger:logRequest:69 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
             ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger:debug:482 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
              ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger:filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus:383 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
               ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger:buildLoggingEventAndAppend:421 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger:callAppenders:257 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                 ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger:appendLoopOnAppenders:270 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                  ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl:appendLoopOnAppenders:51 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                   ch.qos.logback.core.AppenderBase:doAppend:82 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                    biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.GelfLogbackAppender:append:65 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                     biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.GelfLogbackAppender:append:86 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                      biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.GelfLogbackAppender:createGelfMessage:132 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                       biz.paluch.logging.gelf.MdcGelfMessageAssembler:createGelfMessage:33 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                        biz.paluch.logging.gelf.GelfMessageAssembler:createGelfMessage:162 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                         biz.paluch.logging.gelf.GelfMessageAssembler:getValues:216 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                          biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.LogbackLogEvent:getValues:131 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                           biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.LogbackLogEvent:getValue:153 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                            biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.LogbackLogEvent:getSourceClassName:65 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
                             biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.LogbackLogEvent:getCalleeStackTraceElement:74 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
```

The timing values are:

> ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent:getCallerData:258 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1 ms)
>     ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.CallerData:extract:60 (method time = 1 ms, total time = 1 ms)

**What's the reason for the high response times?**

Comment: Can you discuss a little bit more about the code and where/how it is deployed?

Comment: @preethi, have you got anything on your issue? because we are also getting this behavior, if you got something then please provide me the details, it would be helpful